# Unsupported Source

Tags: qgis, raster, wms, qgis-2.14

If I try to save a raster files from a WMS once saved tells me that the source is not supported, "Data Source not supported: /Users/beatriceluise/Desktop/wms/Senza titolo.tif is a raster data source is not supported"

Reason? Solutions?

Comment: What software/application are you using?

Comment: QGIS version 2.14.2